# Can this JQuery code be written using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to represent this code as plain vanilla Javascript so I can better understand how it works for now?

```
$("#id").click(function(){
    var $x = $("#id");
    $x.removeProp("-webkit-animation");
});
```

Essentially I'm using this to tell the code not to play a css animation given that a certain set of parameters are met.

Comment: Which part don't you know how to do in plain Javascript?  The click handler?  Removing a property?  What have you researched and tried?  StackOverflow expects you to have done basic research yourself before posting and then to ask a question about exactly where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just as a side note, anything you do with JQuery you can do with JavaScript. JQuery is JavaScript on the backend, it just creates a shorthand so that we don't have to try so hard!

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm sorry, as I said I'm new to javascript so I was having trouble. I had done research, but I don't know a lot of javascript and couldn't find anything that worked. Sorry to inconvenience everyone.

Answer (score 8):

[`removeProp` removes properties of objects.](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) If that’s definitely what you want, the equivalent is the `delete` operator:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");

element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    delete element["-webkit-animation"];
});
```

If what you really want to do is change a *CSS* property, though, it needs to be an operation on the element’s `style`:

```
element.style.WebkitAnimation = "none";
```

But what you should probably do is change a class instead:

```
element.classList.add("no-animation");
```

and use CSS:

```css
.no-animation {
    -webkit-animation: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [.removeAttribute() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp) to remove an attribute, like style, title, etc.

Or you can use [.removeProperty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to remove a style property (supported in IE9 and above)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/npyjdre8/2/)

```js
(function() {
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.removeAttribute('style');

var aDiv = document.getElementById('aDiv');
aDiv.style.removeProperty('height');
})();
```

```html
<div id="aDiv" style="background-color: green;">Hi</div>
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color: green;">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The delete element is the somewhat equivalent on vanilla javascript of `removeProp()`

```
element = document.getElementById('id');
element.onclick() = function(){
   delete element['-webkit-animation'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help OP

**JS**

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");

element.onClick = function(){
  this.style.removeProperty("-webkit-animation");
};
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is a `removeProperty()` method - albeit I haven't tried to run this code. But it doesn't seem to be listed at MDN.

Comment: @DavidThomas: It does exist. Listed but not thoroughly documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration.

Comment: @minitech: so I see - I tried to run the posted snippet in JS Fiddle and, while it didn't 'work' it didn't generate an error (once the `id` was corrected and the `#` removed). Anyways: [representative demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dfjm23kL/1/), using `color` in place of `-webkit-animation`.

Comment: @DavidThomas: as you tried my solution and it is working as expected you can upvote my answer ;)

Comment: @minitech: thanks for the Url. I knew that this method exist but wad not able find it on MDN